# img src attribute of json value showing small blue colored box in android TextView

Tags: android, json, textview

I have retrieved JSON value to show it in android `TextView`
This is my sample JSON Value

```
    "introtext": "The District Administration Office has sealed the case was underway.&lt;img src=&quot;images/dec_09_Lazimpat_road_b.JPG&quot; alt=&quot;&quot; /&gt;"
```

**I used [Apache Common lang Liabrary](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/) to escape HTML attributes and styles like this.**

```
String str = org.apache.commons.lang3.StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml4(stringValue);
```

**and I have set the value to `TextView` like this**

```
textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(str));
```

**Everything worked fine till here but the `text` in `TextView` is shown like in this image**

[image]

This small blue box is shown where `img src` attribute is there. I've wasted too long time trying to remove this. Please help me how to remove this box from `TextView`. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: html image will have the live url ?

Comment: @user1140237 yah same of them have...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this code:

```
String s = "The District Administration Office has sealed the case was underway.&lt;img src=&quot;images/dec_09_Lazimpat_road_b.JPG&quot; alt=&quot;&quot; /&gt;";
String str = Html.fromHtml(s).toString();
///// Remove all img tags using Regular Expression 
str = str.replaceAll("[<](/)?img[^>]*[>]", "");
textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(str));
```

Comment: Some of the img src tag has url inside. And what can be done for those ? I am waiting for some other answer so I will check it as correct soon. Thanks for your answer.. It was great...

Comment: Do you want to keep the url?

Comment: yah If there is.. Is there any way to grab up URL before replacing the string ?

Comment: But the src is relative, even if you make the link clickable in the TextView, it will be of no use.

Comment: Its ok for now. Let's not give priority to src attribute. Your solution worked. thank you again..

Answer (score 1):

To display Image with html content need to use [BitmapDrawable](http://goo.gl/Ibj0pD) & [ImageGetter](http://goo.gl/kody6l) from HTML too.  Using ImageGetter need to download image convert it in bitmap and dislay in TextView using *[Html.fromHtml](http://goo.gl/6k6vBc)* with Html Content &  instance of the  `Html.ImageGetter`

Below I have give things to resolve the issue mentioned in question

***Suggestion*** 
I'll suggest you to use WebView for the content where you need to display html text

**HTMLImageDrawable**

```
public class HTMLImageDrawable extends BitmapDrawable {

    protected Drawable drawable;

    @Override
    public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
        if (drawable != null) {
            drawable.draw(canvas);
        }
    }
}
```

**HtmlImageParser**

```
 public class HtmlImageParser implements ImageGetter {
    public static final String LOG = HtmlImageParser.class.getName();
    Context c;
    View container;

    public HtmlImageParser(View t, Context c) {
        this.c = c;
        this.container = t;
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
    public Drawable getDrawable(String source) {
        try {
            HTMLImageDrawable urlDrawable = new HTMLImageDrawable();
            ImageGetterAsyncTask asyncTask = new ImageGetterAsyncTask(
                    urlDrawable);

            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 11) {
                asyncTask.execute(source);
            } else {
                asyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR, source);
            }
            return urlDrawable;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(LOG, e.getMessage());
        }
        return null;

    }

    public class ImageGetterAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Drawable> {
        HTMLImageDrawable urlDrawable;

        public ImageGetterAsyncTask(HTMLImageDrawable d) {
            this.urlDrawable = d;
        }

        @Override
        protected Drawable doInBackground(String... params) {
            String source = params[0];
            return fetchDrawable(source);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Drawable result) {
            try {
                if (urlDrawable != null) {
                    urlDrawable.setBounds(0, 0, 0 + result.getIntrinsicWidth(),
                            0 + result.getIntrinsicHeight());

                    urlDrawable.drawable = result;
                    HtmlImageParser.this.container.invalidate();
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e(LOG, e.getMessage());
            }
        }


        public Drawable fetchDrawable(String urlString) {
            try {
//                InputStream is = fetch(urlString);
                URL imageURL = new URL(urlString);
                InputStream inputStream = imageURL.openStream();
                Drawable drawable = Drawable.createFromStream(inputStream, "src");
                drawable.setBounds(0, 0, 0 + drawable.getIntrinsicWidth(),
                        0 + drawable.getIntrinsicHeight());
                return drawable;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                return null;
            }
        }


    }
}
```

Add above two classes.

Set Html Text to TextView

```
TextView htmltext = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.htmltext);
    HtmlImageParser clsUrlimageparser = new HtmlImageParser(htmltext.getRootView(), getActivity());

    String imageviewBaseURL = "http://tfwiki.net/mediawiki/images2/thumb/8/8c/";

    //For multiple image if base url is fix & image path is relative
    String img1 = imageviewBaseURL + "AOE_optimus_reformatted.jpg/180px-AOE_optimus_reformatted.jpg";
    String img2 = imageviewBaseURL + "AnimeMach.jpg/82px-AnimeMach.jpg";
    String text = "Android test image text" +
            "<br /> <img style='width:304px;height:228px;' src='" + img1 + "'/>" +
            "<br /> <img style='width:304px;height:228px;' src='" + img2 + "'/>";
    htmlSpan = Html.fromHtml(text, clsUrlimageparser, null);
    htmltext.setText(htmlSpan);
```

Comment: The image paths in the `src` tag are relative, not absolute. Hence images won't get downloaded.

Comment: @EricB. Okay what about base url ?

Comment: We don't know whether the OP has the base url or not. Secondly, it is discouraged to use the `DefaultHttpClient`, you should use `HttpURLConnection` instead.

Comment: @EricB. thank for you input .. I am aware about & you can update it if this way is helpful. I'll also update it if i got time.. :)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion of using `WebView` I have used another library to parse.

Answer (score 0):

This code

```
public Drawable fetchDrawable(String urlString) {
    try {
        URL imageURL = new URL(urlString);
        InputStream inputStream = imageURL.openStream();
        Drawable drawable = Drawable.createFromStream(inputStream, "src");
        drawable.setBounds(0, 0, 0 + drawable.getIntrinsicWidth(),
                0 + drawable.getIntrinsicHeight());
        return drawable;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Gives me as below

[image]